# Python NLTK how to increment a FreqDist?

Tags: nltk

I'm using the latest version of NLTK and trying to increment using the .inc method but I'm getting an error stating it no longer exists? What is the new method?

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a new method. Instead just manually increment

```
In [1]: from nltk.probability import FreqDist

In [2]: d = {'a': 0, 'b' : 0}

In [3]: fd = FreqDist(d)

In [4]: fd['a'] += 1

In [5]: fd['a']
Out[5]: 1

In [6]: fd['c'] += 1

In [7]: fd['c']
Out[7]: 1
```